# Maven - How do I validate dependencies are available in the declared repositories?

Tags: java, maven

I have just edited the `<repositories />` section of my `pom.xml` file for a project, removing a couple of repo's I thought were unneeded.

I'd like to validate that the declared dependencies are still resolvable in the available repositories.

However, all of the declared dependencies are available in my local repo, so any attempt to build will just use the local ones.

I don't want to simply nuke my local repo, as it takes many hours to download all the dependencies from scratch.

Similarly, I'm not interested in having maven attempt to download all the dependencies, I just want it to ensure that they're all resolvable (including transitive dependencies).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 15):

run
`mvn dependency:analyze`

it will check dependencies for you.

ref:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

Answer (score 2):

The first thing i can say is [not to define repositories in a pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/), cause it will cause many problems in particular for others who are using this project. Furthermore i recommend to use a repository manager which will solve the problem and improve performance during download and will simplify the check of such circumstances which means simply delete the local repo and try to build.

Answer (score 1):

Empty your local repo (rm -rf ~/.m2/repository) and build.

You can't fix the problem of this being time-consuming. There's no way to know if a particular artifact is in a particular external repo without downloading it. If maven just asked 'have you got X?' you'd get false positives from broken artifacts, which are endemic in some repos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I specifically mentioned in my question that I don't want to empty the local repo - it can take several hours to re-download the artifacts.  Besides, this seems a very brute force way to validate a pom.

Comment: And if you don't have one, you could move it out of the way, test, and move it back

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here - but I'd have thought using a repo manager wouldn't solve my problem - which is to validate that my pom can be built by others in a fresh checkout - ie., wouldn't maven resolve the dependencies against the repo manager, still not validating that the remote repositories are declared correctly?

Comment: The repo manager is a caching proxy for the external repos. However, you are correct in some respects; if an external repo suddenly loses its contents, your local repo manager won't.

Answer (score 1):

Emptying the local repo seems to be the only option.
This link may help [prevent maven to resolve dependencies in local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772552/how-to-prevent-maven-to-resolve-dependencies-in-local-repository).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're willing to knock up your own plugin, something that springs to mind would be to have the plugin resolve only the checksums. These checksums are only deployed to the remote repository, after the respective jar/war/zip/whatever artifacts have been already been deployed.

If it takes hours to download all the artifacts, well, then you clearly need a repository manager such as Nexus, or Artifactory, like Karl-Heinz already suggested. It will keep cached versions of your remote artifacts and downloading from it would be a sort matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried mvn validate -U ? I'm no great maven expert but that's what I'd try. (Although I quite regularly blast my local non-third-party report to make absolutely sure the build will work for everyone else).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer but for some reason I have html in pom files so sometimes I add Mvn dependency to pom.xml at the begining:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mvn</id>
        <name>mvn</name>
        <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
...other resps
```

and remove whole .m2/repositories dir or I search for broken files with :

```
grep -R -l -L groupId  --include \*.pom   //Search all that not contain groupId string
```

(execute this in .m2 dir)