# Jenkins Maven Plugin Dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm part of a team that is updating several projects from Maven 2 to Maven 3. We are also migrating to Jenkins(from Continuum) as our Ci. We are having problems with Maven plugin dependencies.

Jenkins doesn't pull in dependent plugins on projects. Example: Site reports fails due to lack of the resources plugin.

Is there a way to make Jenkins maven plugin pull in dependencies for Maven plugins? Failing that, is there a Maven option to verify pom correctness of Maven plugins?

Updated with build log below:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.7:extract-buildnumber (jgit-buildnumber) @ form-letters-api ---
[INFO] Cannot extract Git info, maybe custom build with 'pl' argument is running
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ form-letters-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jboss/jenkins/workspace/formletters/form-letters-api/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ form-letters-api ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /home/jboss/jenkins/workspace/formletters/form-letters-api/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< findbugs-maven-plugin:2.3:findbugs < compile @ form-letters-api <<<
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Form Letters and Templates Manager ................. SUCCESS [ 11.274 s]
[INFO] API:: Form Letters ................................. FAILURE [  8.178 s]
[INFO] Webapp:: Form Letters .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.942 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-23T14:57:23-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/697M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on project form-letters-api: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4--627884439
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.4/maven-site-plugin-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit/2.6/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-webdav/2.5.2/jackrabbit-webdav-2.5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.4/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-exec/1.2/maven-reporting-exec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.3/maven-shared-utils-0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.6/doxia-sink-api-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.6/doxia-logging-api-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.6/doxia-core-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.2/httpclient-4.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/xmlunit/xmlunit/1.5/xmlunit-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.6/doxia-module-xhtml-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.6/doxia-module-apt-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.6/doxia-module-xdoc-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.6/doxia-module-fml-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-markdown/1.6/doxia-module-markdown-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.2.1/pegdown-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.1.4/parboiled-java-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.4/parboiled-core-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.1/asm-tree-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.1/asm-analysis-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/4.1/asm-util-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.6/doxia-decoration-model-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.6/doxia-site-renderer-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-tools/2.0/velocity-tools-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-chain/commons-chain/1.1/commons-chain-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.1/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.1/dom4j-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/sslext/sslext/1.2-0/sslext-1.2-0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.8/struts-core-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-taglib/1.3.8/struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-tiles/1.3.8/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-integration-tools/1.6/doxia-integration-tools-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.4.3/plexus-archiver-2.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.8/plexus-io-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.5/commons-compress-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.2/xz-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.15/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.25/jetty-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.25/jetty-util-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/opt/maven/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

Comment: Does you build work on command line?

Comment: It works locally for everything except the release (not distributing the site.xml to force Jenkins builds). The process makes it to the maven-release copying the artifacts over before it bombs.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the log output...

Comment: This error was resolved, it was Maven2/Maven 3 plugin incompatibility. Is there a an automatic way to verify plugin versions?

Comment: In which way would you like to verify the plugin versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven - How do I validate dependencies are available in the declared repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490135/maven-how-do-i-validate-dependencies-are-available-in-the-declared-repositorie)